# ASP.net - Datatables become Nothing on PostBack

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable, postback

I am filling a **datatable** on page_load in order to use it later on.

```
Public serviceTable as Datatable

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            If IsPostBack = False Then
                GetData()
            End If
End Sub


Private Sub getData()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
        Try
            cmd = New SqlCommand(("dbo.getListofServices"), cn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(ds)
            ServiceTable = ds.Tables(0)
        Catch ex As SqlClient.SqlException
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            If (IsNothing(da) = False) Then da.Dispose()
            If (IsNothing(cmd) = False) Then cmd.Dispose()
        End Try
End Sub
```

I want to use the serviceTable later on Button_Click

```
Protected Sub btnView_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnView.Click

    Try
                If ServiceTable.Rows.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
                Repeater1.DataSource = ServiceTable
                Repeater1.DataBind()

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
    End Sub
```

I am getting an error that says **ServiceTable doesn't refer to an Object.** 
Is it possible that the datatable is emptying on postback?
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following statement while declaring Service Table:

```
Public serviceTable as New DataTable()
```

Hope this helps..

```
If Not (Session("MyData") Is Nothing) Then
Session("MyData")=Servicetable
```

After the Post Back , retieve the saved data set from the session variable

as

```
ServiceTable= = (DataTable)Session["MyData"];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The error is no longer **Servicetable doesn't refer to an object**, but instead now on post back **Servicetable.rows.count returns 0**

Comment: i think the values does not hold between post backs..so.you need to make use of session variables..